# Class requires api level 21 - JobService ( Firebase Jobdispatcher)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

I'm want to implement `Firebase JobDispatcher` for running background operations. But while Extending JobService, it's showing error as `class requires api level 21`. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `import android.app.job.JobService` with `import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService`

Answer (score 0):

`JobService` is added in API level 21, so the minimum required sdk version should be 21, otherwise it will show error `class requires api level 21`

in your `app` gradle file set your minimum sdk version 21

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

Refrence :- [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService)